# TYPO3 object storage add existing item

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 7.6.18. I need to add an existing item to an object storage. I see that it doesn't add the item.

```
$editUser = $this->userRepository->findByUid($userUid);
$newSmile = $this->serviceRepository->findByUid($smileUid);
if ($editUser && $newSmile) {
    $smileUid = $newSmile->getUid();
    $editUser->addSmile($newSmile);
    $this->userRepository->update($editUser);
    $persistenceManager->persistAll();
}
```

Help me please. 
Model user, all that touch smile object storage. I added my User model. Sorry I must write something. I must write more.

```
/**
 * smiles
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service>
 */
protected $smile = '';

/**
 * Returns the smiles
 *
 * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service> $smile
 */
public function getSmile()
{
    return $this->smile;
}

/**
 * Sets the smile
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setSmile($smile)
{
    $this->smile = $smile;
}


/**
 * Adds a smile to the smile
 *
 * @param \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service $smile
 * @return void
 * @api
 */
public function addSmile(\Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service $smile)
{
    $this->smile->attach($smile);
}

/**
 * Removes a smile from the smile
 *
 * @param \Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service $smile
 * @return void
 * @api
 */
public function removeSmile(\Fhk\Feusersplus\Domain\Model\Service $smile)
{
    $this->smile->detach($smile);
}
```

TCA of table tx_feusersplus_domain_model_usersmile

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title'    => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:userSmile',
        'label' => 'uid_local',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'hideTable' => true,
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'iconfile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath('feusersplus') . 'Resources/Public/Icons/tx_feusersplus_domain_model_hut.gif'

    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'uid_local,uid_foreign'
    ],
    'types' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => 'sys_language_uid;;;;1-1-1, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource;;1, uid_local, uid_foreign,--div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access'],
    ],
    'palettes' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => ''],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_language',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY sys_language.title',
                'items' => [
                    ['LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages', -1],
                    ['LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.default_value', 0]
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND tx_fefiles_domain_model_photo.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        't3ver_label' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            ]
        ],
        'uid_local' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:user',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
                'minitems' => 1,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ]
        ],
        'uid_foreign' => [
            'exclude' => 1,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:smile',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'foreign_table' => 'tx_feusersplus_domain_model_service',
//                'foreign_field' => 'uid',
//                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND tx_feusersplus_domain_model_service.sys_language_uid=###REC_FIELD_sys_language_uid### ',
                'foreign_match_fields' => [
                    'type' => 1
                ],

                'minitems' => 1,
                'maxitems' => 1,
            ]
        ],
        'crdate' => array(
            'exclude' => 0,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:feusersplus/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:crdate',
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 10,
                'max' => 20,
                'eval' => 'date',
                'checkbox' => '0',
                'default' => ''
            )
        ),
    ],
];
```

By the way, I use this table for MM relation.

Comment: Can you post the model of the user?

Comment: I added user model. Hope for your help)

Comment: Is there no error message when trying to add an item?

Comment: no, I don't see error, it just does't add

Comment: Please add the snippet where you inject the persistenceManager

Comment: $persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get("TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager");

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize every object storage in your model by:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->smile = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
}
```

Comment: sorry I clear all cache and try, but it still not add same  object. May be something wrong in TCA ?

Comment: I added TCA ) And when I add item to this table via objectStorage, it does't set crdate , why ?

Comment: This seems to be a MM table. You don't need a TCA for a mm table. A model has the fields `uid`, `pid`, etc.

Comment: I need TCA, because I need solution, I must know time, when item was added to object storage

Comment: I find a German example, maybe it helps you understanding the relation between models with MM: http://www.typo3tiger.de/blog/post/typo3-bidirektionale-mm-relation-tca-extbase.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152120/discussion-between-mikael-and-thomas-loffler).